# Convergence of three sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the sequences an <= bn <= cn eventually, and both an and cn are convergent. Is bn necessarily convergent?

Comment: You can only draw this conclusion if the $b_n$ are "squeezed" between the $a_n$ and the $c_n$. That is, if $c_n-a_n\to 0$. Otherwise, the $b_n$ could oscillate between $\lim a_n$ and $\lim c_n$ without converging.

Answer (score 2):

No. Consider $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: a_n = -1, c_n = 1$ and $b_n = (-1)^n$.

However, if $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(c_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ both converge to **the same** point, then we can make an assertion.